Colleagues mad for 'exposing' their secret relationship
I work for a Dutch enterprise, and in the last 6 months, I've been working on a project with Alice (F) and Bob (M), both in their late twenties (so am I). Bob is a vendor's employee, but Alice is my direct colleague.
We've been working together almost everyday on-site spending a lot of time together, going to lunch together (either in the cafeteria, or places outside), attending borrels (Dutch cocktail party), and overall, we've had a nice time with each other, as well as a very efficient and productive working relationship.
A few days ago, I got to the office during lunchtime. Alice and Bob had already gone to have lunch, of course. As I was settling in, another colleague passed by, and asked if I knew where Alice is. I told them that she's having lunch with Bob. They said thanks, and that was the end of a very short conversation.
Later that day, Alice came to me, all emotional, accusing me of 'exposing' her secret romance with Bob knowingly and out of malice. I explained to her that as someone who's been working closely with both of you and had an 'office romance' in the past that got serious, I had no idea they're in a relationship in the first place. I innocuously just told a colleague that she's off to lunch with Bob, and I believe it is illogical to infer from such a simple answer that there's an ongoing relationship, and before that, I wasn't talking about any relationships to anyone, simply because I wasn't even aware of such a thing.
Alice simply won't accept my explanation, and she wants me to move out from the trio. I disagreed, explaining that our project is quite important to me, and we're in a position that we can swap Bob with someone else from the vendor. Then, she threatened to quit the company altogether, if I don't exit the project.
All of this don't really sound like Alice. I believe she's under a lot pressure and stress, and I regret the slightest possibility that I might've played a part in it. How can I help her without losing my own position?

Does Alice and Bob being entangled violate any company policy and/or create a conflict of interest? Is that what Alice is potentially upset about? Is there anything that prevents them from "going public"?

What does your supervisor think? Allow her to quit if she feel that passionated about your involvement in the project.

@Hilmar There's no explicit prohibition of office romance that's noted in the handbook, but I think this relationship could possibly affect the relationship between the company and the vendor. It's very unlikely though.

@Donald My supervisor believes it's Alice's problem, and they are going to remove me from the project. However, I still want to do right by Alice, hence why I'm coming to this community.

@Kinen - So it’s Alice’s problem but your being removed from that project that appears to suggest something else entirely. Why do you feel responsible to “do right by Alice”, when I assume, your just their coworker?

@Donald I get your point, I'm trying to keep myself in check that I'm not delving too deep into this. My initial reasoning was that Alice just started her career (less than a year), and she's quite talented too, and it would be such a shame seeing her waste her potential over such kerfuffle.

@Kinen - It’s not your responsibility to look out for Alice. Does Alice even want your help?

Before this, did either Alice or Bob ask you to keep their lunch meeting quiet?  Did they give any hint that they didn't want it mentioned?  (If not, how did they expect you to know?)

I can read this again and again, I still don't see how the statement "they are having lunch" could be understood equal to "they have a romance". This is the first and probably the only thing you should clarify with Alice. Did she tell anyone about her romance? Then you can help the situation by clarifying that it was her to reveal it, not you. If she revealed something at all, we don't know that. How you could help Alice depends on the problem she is having and the reason that actually created the problem.

You can't make anyone feel a specific way. If Alice is acting as if you did something wrong that is her projecting. That is too bad. Adults are allowed to have relationships.

@puck If Alice believed that the relationship was secret and/or illicit then anything pointing to her involvement with Bob could trigger her lashing out.  It's not what the OP did that caused this incident, but what Alice believes the OP's actions imply.

All you can do is hope that she will calm down and accept your innocence. I do not see any way to help her do so which will not come across as guilty, self-serving, or intrusive other than trying to give her space until this storm passes. You could try asking your manager to talk to her about it, though that involves telling another person about the relationship, possibly the person she was trying to hide it from.
If the secret is really out (she may be misreading what someone else said) and she is unhappy about this, there is nothing you can really do to fix it, even if it had been your error.
You can't have a workplace without people, and you can't have people without drama. Trying to stay out of it is the only thing that works, and as you have found, even that does not always work. Luckily it usually blows over if you refuse to engage with it.

The question here is: does Alice and Bob being entangled violate any company polices (of either company) and/or create a conflict of interest and is that Alice is potentially upset about?
Most companies explicitly discourage people who are in close personal relationships (family members, romantic partners) from working on the same project or being in each other's reporting chain. For good reasons: you don't want professional conflict (which is a fact of life) spill over into personal life. Most companies have even stricter guidelines for working with vendors.
It may be useful to do a little research and figure out what the "legal" lay of the land is so you can advice Alice properly.
Chances are what they are doing is not ok. If they are serious about their relationship (great for them !) their best course of action would be to come clean and disclose it to their food chain. The likely outcome would be that one of them will be removed from the project. While that might feel like a short term loss, its likely to be a long term gain for both of them. They can focus on their relationship without work getting in the way and proactively disclosing builds trust and will be seen as personal strength.
No of course, the tricky part will be how to communicate this all to Alice, who currently is furious at you. Maybe you can start with an apology (despite having done nothing wrong), that always helps people to simmer down. Let them know that you are happy for them and that you want to help. Take your hints from her reaction.

I'd quibble with "stark raving mad", which has other connotations re sanity, and substitute "furious". Otherwise -- after a pause to let her calm down a bit? -- this is a good point and a good approach,

"companies discourage people who are in personal relationships....  For good reasons: you don't want professional conflict spill over into personal life." Well of course the reason is the opposite: The company doesn't want personal conflicts or favoring to spill into the company.

@keshlam I agree with you and have made that change.

@deep64blue while you may be right, it is up to the poster of the answer to make that edit if they so wish, and while you are there, as the "English" expert you should change "summer" for "simmer"...
